# Problem with installing 'concurrently' in node project

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, concurrently

I'm trying to install concurrently but facing this issue

```
PS D:\devconnector> npm i concurrently
npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...TURE-----\r\nVersion:'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\baner\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-04-24T08_55_51_704Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Did you try [this](https://github.com/LLK/scratch-gui/issues/4328#issuecomment-592990182) ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a cache issue. You can clear npm cache with the following command and try installing the package again.

```
npm cache clean --force
npm i concurrently
```